# SQL. how to compare values and from two table, and report per-row results

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two Tables.
table A

```
id  name    Size
===================
1   Apple   7
2   Orange  15 
3   Banana  22
4   Kiwi    2
5   Melon   28
6   Peach   9
```

And Table B

```
id  size
==============
1   14
2   5 
3   31
4   9
5   1
6   16
7   7
8   25
```

My desired result will be (add one column to Table A, which is the number of rows in Table B that have **size** smaller than **Size** in Table A)

```
id  name    Size   Num.smaller.in.B
==============================
1   Apple   7      2
2   Orange  15     5
3   Banana  22     6
4   Kiwi    2      1
5   Melon   28     7
6   Peach   9      3
```

Both Table A and B are pretty huge. Is there a clever way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is *pretty huge*? Is there any kind of grouping or is it actually comparing all rows?

Comment: is peach 6 or 9 in table a?

Comment: @Beth. shall be 9. Sorry about the typo

Comment: @dnoeth. Table A has 7,000,000  rows and Table B has 20,000 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query it's helpful

```
SELECT id,
name,
Size,
(Select count(*) From TableB Where TableB.size<Size)
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to get your result involves a non-equi-join, which will be a *product join* in Explain. First duplicating 20,000 rows, followed by 7,000,000 * 20,000 comparisons and a huge intermediate spool before the count.

There's a solution based on OLAP-functions which is usually quite efficient:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   -- Do a cumulative count of the rows of table #2
   -- sorted by size, i.e. count number of rows with a size #2 less size #1   
   Sum(CASE WHEN NAME = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)
   Over (ORDER BY SIZE, NAME DESC ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
FROM
 ( -- mix the rows of both tables, an empty name indicates rows from table #2
   SELECT id, name, size
   FROM a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, '', size
   FROM b
 ) AS dt
-- only return the rows of table #1
QUALIFY name <> ''
```

If there are multiple rows with the same size in table #2 you better count before the Union to reduce the size:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   -- Do a cumulative sum of the counts of table #2
   -- sorted by size, i.e. count number of rows with a size #2 less size #1   
   Sum(CASE WHEN NAME =''  THEN id ELSE 0 end)
   Over (ORDER BY SIZE, NAME DESC ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
FROM
 ( -- mix the rows of both tables, an empty name indicates rows from table #2
   SELECT id, name, size
   FROM a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Count(*), '', SIZE
   FROM b
   GROUP BY SIZE
 ) AS dt
-- only return the rows of table #1
QUALIFY NAME <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no clever way of doing that, you just need to join the tables like this:

```
select a.*, b.size
from TableA a join TableB b on a.id = b.id
```

To improve performance you'll need to have indexes on the id columns.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify. Let me clarify, I want a column with information that is the [number of rows in Table B that have size-value smaller than Size in Table A]

Comment: except he doesn't want to join on id, he's joining on size less than size in other table

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
select 
  id,
  name,
  a.Size, 
  sum(cnt) as sum_cnt
from
  a inner join
  (select size, count(*) as cnt from b group by size) s on
  s.size < a.size
group by id,name,a.size
```

if you're working with large tables.  Indexing table `b`'s `size` field could help.  I'm also assuming the values in table `B` converge, that there's many duplicates you don't care about, other than you want to count them.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1df8c/3)

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh solution is perfectly correct, another similar solution is using CROSS JOIN as shown below

```
use tempdb
create table dbo.A (id int identity, name varchar(30), size int );
create table dbo.B (id int identity, size int);
go
insert into dbo.A (name, size)
values ('Apple',   7)
,('Orange',    15) 
,('Banana',  22)
,('Kiwi',    2 )
,('Melon',   28)
,('Peach',   6 )

insert into dbo.B (size)
values (14), (5),(31),(9),(1),(16), (7),(25)
go
-- using cross join
select a.*, t.cnt 
from dbo.A
cross apply (select cnt=count(*) from dbo.B where B.size < A.size) T(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT 
A.id,A.name,A.size,Count(B.size) 
from A,B 
where A.size>B.size 
group by A.size 
order by A.id;
```